# How to join a voice channel when command is typed discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I am working on a basic bot that joins a voice channel when //join is typed in chat. I wan't it to join the voice channel that the user who sent the message is in. How do I detect the channel that the user is in then join it afterwards?

```
client.on("message", msg => {
    if (msg.content === "^join") {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get that voice channel of the user that issued the command using `message.member.voice.channel`.

```js
const channel = message.member.voice.channel;
channel.join();
```